# iPhone pixel density

Tags: iphone, ppi

Apple declares for iPhone (not retina display) 163 ppi but if you use below calculation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density#Calculation_of_monitor_PPI

the result is 164.825201164068.

What calculation uses Apple for it?

Answer (score 1):

The resolution is exactly 163 ppi if you assume a diagonal of 3.5392 inch, and that is probably within the manufacturing tolerance, so I assume that Apple specified the lowest resolution that is possible within the tolerance.